# Events Fired in Background Thread Ignored

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I'm running a C# forms application which starts a thread to acquire some data. This thread has some events *inside* it i.e: the events fire in the thread and are supposed to be captured by the same thread. However, the thread's events don't seem to be firing. Any clues?

```
private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(kinect.onlineRun);
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
    }
```

inside the thread:

```
void PointCreated(object sender, IdEventArgs e) // a certain event that should fire and it doesn't
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Event Fired!");            
        }



public void onlinerun()
{
    Console.WriteLine("run started"); // this is printed on console
    while (true)
    {
      do_some_work();
      //this work could result in the PointCreated event firing
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no console in WinForm applications. Use Debug.WriteLine instead to go to VS2010 output window.

Comment: Actually, it's printing things other than events nicely, I chose the project type to be a console application, but in its program I run a window on an STAThread

Comment: How are you firing the event?

Comment: I don't know, its a library, I just have an event handler for it.

Comment: @BrianGideon Why not? I always use WinForm+Console while developing codes

Comment: @L.B: Yes, indeed. I just tried it and when no console window exists it goes to the VS output window automatically. I wonder if this has changed or perhaps it has always been that way and I never noticed before.

Comment: @BrianGideon it’s not just that; a WinForms project can easily create a console manually (or even multiple), or be changed to the "console" subsystem so that the OS creates the first console for it.

Comment: How do you know it's not just a problem with the library? Does it work properly if you run the task synchronously on the main thread? I.e., in btnPlay_Click(), call onlinerun() directly instead of starting it in a new thread (the UI will become unresponsive).

Comment: @romkyns: Is there a way to do that without calling `AllocConsole` or setting the project type to Console Application?

Comment: It's possible the thread is throwing an exception that won't display because it's in a background thread. Try putting it in a try/catch and spit out the caught exception to the Console/Debugger.

Comment: @BrianGideon I don’t know of a way to do that without one of those things.

Comment: Well, it does work properly when I'm running things synchronously. I think I detected the problem though, pretty weird though. It seems like if I'm doing lots of processing in my main thread, the other thread doesn't capture events, so when I reduced the processing in the main thread, it worked well. Still trying to dig up things though and any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

Give something like this a try:

Assuming your calling class is called Controller and your delegate is called ControlEventHandler...

```
private void PointCreated(object sender, IdEventArgs e)
{
    // Ensure the event was received in the calling thread
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        if (e != null)
        {
            // We aren't in the correct thread so pass on the event
            this.BeginInvoke(new Controller.ControllerEventHandler(this.PointCreated), new object[] { sender, e });
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Event Fired!");

            // TODO: Do some stuff here
        }
    }
}
```